# I would like to display the HINDI language in FPDF by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display the utf8-unicode-ci collation data from MySQL to FPDF. I 
have used the function `iconv("UTF-8", "", "£")` but is doesn't work.
It only shows the questions marks.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: FPDF does not support UTF8

Good news: there's [an extension](http://acko.net/blog/ufpdf-unicode-utf-8-extension-for-fpdf/), that adds that support

More bad news: you might have some trouble generating hindi fonts

Somewhat good news: you could move to [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) which is much better at handling utf8 (and is more modern in general) than FPDF